# Can't Close SerialPort, arduino sending with 200hz data to serial monitor

Tags: c#, arduino

Halllo

I have made my first project and it works, well sort of, I can not get it to close serial port.

I am running 200hz in the Serialmonitor and the save funktion works perfect.

I suspect that it attempts to read data while I am trying to close the port.

It does not come up with an error but hanging in the debugger trying to close the port.

**MY CODE IN VISUAL STUDIO 2015:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    namespace Arduino_Serial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort myport;
        private DateTime datetime;
        private string in_data1;
        private int runtime_sec = 0;
        private float runtime_milis = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Start_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 115200;
            myport.PortName = Port_name_tb.Text;
            myport.Parity = Parity.None;
            myport.DataBits = 8;
            myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myport.DataReceived += Myport_DataReceived;
            try
            {
                myport.Open();
                timer2.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Enabled = true;

                Data_tb.Text = "\"Arduino\"" + "\n";
                Data_tb.AppendText("Time" + "\t" + "Raw_data" + "\t" + "MAP" + "\n");
                Data_tb.AppendText("Sec " + "\t" + "Raw_data" + "\t" + "KPA" + "\n");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }

        void Myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            in_data1 = myport.ReadLine();
            Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
        }

        private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datetime = DateTime.Now;
            string time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;
            Data_tb.AppendText(("\n")+ (runtime_milis) + ("\t")+ in_data1 );
        }

        private void Stop_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                myport.ReadTimeout = 1000000000;
                myport.Close();
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                runtime_milis = 0;
                runtime_sec = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error");
            }
        }

        private void Save_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                datetime = DateTime.Now;
                String time = datetime.Year + "-"+ datetime.Month + "-"+ datetime.Day + "_" + datetime.Hour + "." + datetime.Minute + "." + datetime.Second;
                string pathfile = @"C:\DATA\";
                string filename = "Arduino_" + time + ".msl";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathfile + filename, Data_tb.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex3.Message, "Error");
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            runtime_sec++;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                runtime_milis++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `https://github.com/ms-iot/remote-wiring`. This is the official way of using the Arduino from Windows 10. There are several examples and documentation on the internet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful, that describes the problem you're having or the question you're asking. *Arduino* and *C#* are both things you can supply in tags, leaving your entire title as *Serial*, and that in no way is descriptive. Your title should be something that will have relevance when a future reader sees it in a search result.

Comment: Thanks Zak, I am trying a different route where I have a program in the arduino doing some stuff and then writing to the serial monitor from the arduino, and that is the data I am catching with this project.

Hope this is better Ken White!

Comment: I've read somewhere that Serial ports aren't closeable via software. Perhaps you should consider `Dispose` method for it.

Comment: Pretty classic deadlock, it is caused by Invoke().  Which can only complete when the UI thread is idle.  But it is not idle, it called Close().  Which cannot complete until the event handler completes.  Always avoid Invoke(), use BeginInvoke() instead.  Your next problem is in_data1, it is not thread-safe, pass the string as an argument instead.